# unidirectional one-to-many relation without join table

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Book {

    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column private Long bookId;

    @Column private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="bookId")
    private List<Chapter> chapters=new ArrayList<Chapter>();
.....

@Entity
@Table
public class Chapter {

    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue
    private Long cid;

    @Column private String name;

    @Column private Long bookId;
....
```

What annotation should I use in Chapter.bookId to refer Book.bookId, so that chapter.bookid will take the generated value of Book.bookId while inserting a new Book .

```
    Book bk=new Book();
    bk.setName("b1");

    Chapter ch=new Chapter();
    ch.setName("b1c1");
    bk.getChapters().add(ch);
```

I get this error
    Hibernate: insert into Book (name) values (?)
    Hibernate: insert into Chapter (bookId, name) values (?, ?)
    19:56:59,094 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:234 - Column 'bookId' cannot be null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to set `Chapter.bookId` yourself or change the reference in `Chapgter` from `Long` to `Book`, add the `@ManyToOne` annotation and set the reference to the book manually.

In this case, the owning side of the relation is actually `Chapter`, i.e. a chapter defines which book it belongs to.

Comment: Yes. In this case, most people will add a convenience method on Book (called addChapter or some such) which combines adding the chapter to the collection and setting the Chapter's Book reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Column(nullable=true) if you really need null value, otherwise as have been said in previous answer - you need to set it manually, adding Chapter to list doesn't set bookId